# Mustache , iterating over JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

I have a JSON array of objects, and am trying to work out how to display them in Mustache.js. The array can be variable in length and content.

Example:

```
[ Object { id="1219", 0="1219", title="Lovely Book ", url= "myurl} , Object { id ="1220" , 0="1220 , title "Lovely Book2" , url="myurl2"}]
```

Ive tried:

```
        $.getJSON('http://myjsonurl?type=json', function(data) {
        var template = $('#personTpl').html();
        var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
        $('#test').html(html);
```

and the template:

```
 <script id="personTpl" type="text/template">
TITLE: {{#data}} {{title}} IMAGE: {{image}}
<p>LINK: <a href="{{blogURL}}">{{type}}</a></p>  {{/data}} 
</script>
```

but that doesn't display anything.

I've tried putting the JSON into an array, and then accessing it directly using  `products[1]` something like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://myjsonurl?type=json", function(json) 
{
    var products = [];

    $.each(json, function(i, product)
    {           
            var product =
            {           
                Title:product.title,
                Type:product.type,
                Image:product.image             
            };

            products.push(product);
        ;       
    });     

    var template = "<h1>Title: {{ Title }}</h1> Type: {{ Type }} Image : {{ Image }}";


    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, products[1]);
    $('#json').html(html);                      

});
```

which will display one record fine, but how can I iterate over them and display all ?

Comment: if the array of objects can be variable in content it doesn't sound well suited for a template

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a single JSON object that looks like:

```
var json = { id:"1220" , 0:"1220", title:"Lovely Book2", url:"myurl2" };
var template = $('#personTpl').html();
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, json);
$('#test').html(html);
```

So something like this should work:

```
$.getJSON('http://myjsonurl?type=json', function(data) {
var template = $('#personTpl').html();
$.each(data, function(key,val) {

        var html = Mustache.to_html(template, val);
        $('#test').append(html);
});

});
```

Comment: ah, didn't realise the Mustache render had to be in an each. Thanks!

Comment: rending Mustache in a loop like that is pretty inefficient

Comment: True. The above answers OP's question but is far from efficient. What would be better is to pass e.g. { array: [ { title: 'one' }, { title: 'two' } ] } Then you can use them in the template like: {{#array}}<h1>{{title}}</h1>{{/array}}

Comment: The Ruby implementation had (at one point) support for implicit sections; that is, if the rendering context was an array rather than an object, it would automatically loop over the context and render the template once per element. I'm not sure it still supports this, but it was a handy feature :)

Answer (score 2):

For your template to work the way you have it, your json needs to look like this

```
{
  "data": [
    { "id":"1219", "0":"1219", "title":"Lovely Book ", "url": "myurl"},
    { "id":"1219", "0":"1219", "title":"Lovely Book ", "url": "myurl"},
    { "id":"1219", "0":"1219", "title":"Lovely Book ", "url": "myurl"}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should make eliminate the need to do an each statement

```
var json = { id:"1220", 0:"1220", title:"Lovely Book2", url:"myurl2" };
var stuff = {stuff: json}; 
var template = $('#personTpl').html();
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, stuff);
$('#test').html(html);
```

In your Template, do this to loop through stuff

```
<script id="personTpl" type="text/template">
{{#stuff}}
   TITLE:  {{title}} IMAGE: {{image}}
   <p>LINK: <a href="{{blogURL}}">{{type}}</a></p>  
{{/stuff}} 
</script>
```